# Could not connect to development server on new projet on React Native 0.37 (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I just created a new project on react-native version 0.37 on iOS.
I've setting up this part of info.plist

[image]
server is running :

[image]

But this loads loop on this url:

> url: /index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false

And I finally get this error :

[image]

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Mich",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.37.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have never had this error before by starting a new project. Someone can explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Had same problem but it is intermittent. Once I redeploy to app to the sim it goes away..

Comment: Are you running the application on an emulator or a device? If the latter, I manage to get it working with some extra code on `AppDelegate.m`. Let me know if it is the case. Otherwise, does the development server receive the emulator's request? If you, you might be facing a timeout error, since the server takes a bit to transpile all files. In any other case you might want to check that the emulator has access to the sever by opening `localhost:8081` on Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, i press CMD+R and during server is loading, i press CMD + D and i press on Debug JS remotly.